# Insert a button into a div on a jsp using document ready

Tags: java, spring, jsp, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout.jsp that I am using to build a page using multiple other jsp's.

In my main content jsp pages I have a button or two. In the current version I am positioning the div with the buttons relatively.

I am switching the way the page is designed. I created a div in my layout page to place the buttons into. I gave it an appButtonDiv class.

The issue I am running into is I do not know how to create a button insert it into the div.  I would like to do this on document ready.

Here is the div I want to put the button(s) into.

```
    <div class="row-fluid verticalmenubottom">
        <div class="span12 verticalMenuCell appButtonDiv"></div>
    </div>
```

Below is a example button.

```
 <button type="submit" id="searchButton" name="searchButton"
                                value='<spring:message code="Generic.Search"/>'/>
                        Search</button>
```

There are some cases where I will have multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't JSP competence, however you are asking how to add content to an element on document ready.

Using JQuery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(init);
```

else without JQuery, you might use the onload event of your body element:

```
<body onload="init()">...</body>
```

Then declare this function in your script tag:

```
function init() {
//this executes on document ready

//create your elements
    var externDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var internDiv = document.createElement('div');
    externDiv.className = 'row-fluid verticalmenubottom';
    internDiv .className = 'span12 verticalMenuCell appButtonDiv';
    externDiv.appendChild(internDiv);

//find your button and put the new elements in it (check that your jsp don't change the id client-side)
    var btn = document.getElementById('searchButton');
    btn.appendChild(externDiv);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: I had to tweak it a little bit but that is pretty much what I was looking for.  The only thing I have left to figure out now is how to tie it to the form submit :)

Comment: You can add a click event on your new divs and bind it to call document.formName.submit()

Answer (score 1):

You mean u want to insert a button inside a button?
or create another button inside the div?

```
<div class="row-fluid verticalmenubottom">
    <div id="button1" class="span12 verticalMenuCell appButtonDiv"></div>
    <div id="button2" class="span12 verticalMenuCell appButtonDiv"></div>
</div>
```

or i miss something @@ ?

Comment: I am looking to add a button to a div that does not currently have any content, it is a placeholder.